# How to plot slope fields in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, ode

I am new to Matlab (literally just downloaded it) and I would like to know how to create a slope field and integral curves.

My equation is dy/dx = x^2/(1-y^2).

My attempt at code is:

```
Ffun = @(X,Y)X.^2./(1-Y.^2);               % function f(x,y)
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-5:.5:5,-5:.5:5); % choose the plot sizes
DY=Ffun(X,Y); DX=ones(size(DY)); % generate the plot values 
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY);
hold on;
contour(X,Y,DY,10);
```

I keep getting: "Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. In `@(X,Y)X^2/(1-Y^2)`
I also get blank graphs.

Also, it would be nice if I could get the positive, negative, and zero slopes in different colors.

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are producing `inf` values when evaluating this function, as it has poles around Y=+-1. The `inf` makes the plot to scale to absurdity....  To still plot this you can transform  all `inf` values to `NaN` (not a number does not show in a plot) as follows:

```
DY(isinf(DY))=NaN;
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY);
```

Comment: I think it worked thank you!
Do you also happen to know how change the color of the slopes based on the the sign of the slope (ie. positive, negative, or zero)?

Comment: Actually, so I tried to change the scale of the plot from (-5,5) to (-2,2) by increments of 0.1:

    `Ffun = @(X,Y)X.^2./(1-Y.^2);               % function f(x,y)
    [X,Y]=meshgrid(-2:.5:2,-2:.5:2); % choose the plot sizes
    DY(isinf(DY))=NaN; DX=ones(size(DY));
    quiver(X,Y,DX,DY); % generate the plot values 
    hold on;
    contour(X,Y,DY,5);`

and I get this error: "Error using quiver (line 55)
The size of X must match the size of U or the number of columns of U."

Comment: you forgot to define `DY=Ffun(X,Y);`